# Skipping attributes in the select clause while using group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, database

I am using HR schema,Employees and Departments table. I was asked during the interview following query.
Write a query to print department_name,department_no, count of all employees in corresponding department,but the condition is I can use only one attribute with group by clause.

```
        SQL> desc employees;
     Name                                                  Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
     EMPLOYEE_ID                                           NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
     FIRST_NAME                                                     VARCHAR2(20)
     LAST_NAME                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
     EMAIL                                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
     PHONE_NUMBER                                                   VARCHAR2(20)
     HIRE_DATE                                             NOT NULL DATE
     JOB_ID                                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
     SALARY                                                         NUMBER(8,2)
     COMMISSION_PCT                                                 NUMBER(2,2)
     MANAGER_ID                                                     NUMBER(6)
     DEPARTMENT_ID                                                  NUMBER(4)

SQL> desc departments
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 DEPARTMENT_ID                                         NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 DEPARTMENT_NAME                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 MANAGER_ID                                                     NUMBER(6)
 LOCATION_ID                                                    NUMBER(4)
```

I tried various options to frame query, I used having clause with count(employee_id)  but to no effect.Any help appreciated

Comment: There is no department_no in the tables description, do you mean department_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting two values from the same table, and one is the key (or more importantly, unique), you can just apply an aggregate function to the other one:

```
select d.department_id,
  min(d.department_name) as department_name,
  count(e.employee_id)
from departments d
left join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b3b1/3). Either `min` or `max`of the name would work, and you only need to group by the ID. You *could* do it the other way around, but name is less likely to be unique.

---

Not sure if it would count, but as an exercise in futility, you could also just concatenate the values:

```
select d.department_id ||' '||d.department_name,
  count(e.employee_id)
from departments d
left join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id ||' '|| d.department_name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b3b1/1).

You can `lpad` the `department_id` to maintain the illusion that they are separate columns, sort of. (It doesn't show up well as a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b3b1/2) though).

Pointless hack, but then it's an interview question so maybe that's appropriate, and seems to just about fulfil the wording you used. Depending on how 'attribute' is defined - I'm taking it to mean a single expression here, which may be a stretch...

Comment: It worked perfectly.Great!I am skipping left outer join and getting same result any specific reason to use join,like performance or something?

Comment: @user3516296 - the left jpin would show you any departments with no employees, if there were any.